# Inserting formula using For Next Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to concatenate a column's worth of fields (~900 at the moment) from two other fields in the same sheet.

I am trying to create a macro to enter the formula into Column C. I can't keep the quotation marks straight.

```vb
Sub Concatenate()
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Con As String
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Set WS = Sheets("Vlookups")
    
    'Set upper range of Loop
    LastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Set to Active Worksheet
    Worksheets("Vlookups").Activate
    
    'Explicitly reference the Sheet when calling for any Range or Cell
    With WS

        For i = 2 To LastRow
    
            Con = "=CONCATENATE(" & .Cells(i, 15).Select & "," & "-" & "," & .Cells(i, 16).Select & ")"
    
            .Cells(i, 3).Select
            ActiveCell.Formula = Con
        
        Next i
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

Comment: You can also shorten a little to: `Con = "=CONCATENATE(" & .Cells(i, 15) & ",""-""," & .Cells(i, 16) & ")"`

Comment: @Rory I have taken out the .Select portion as you suggested, I just wasn't sure if referencing the Cell in this format would work while inputting a formula. It still is inputting nothing in the cells. I even tried changing `ActiveCell.Formula = Con` to `Selection.Formula = Con` and no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- There is no need to `Select` or `Activate`.
- There is no need to loop.
- It looks like you are finding the last row based on column C, but then writing the formula into column C, which seems suspect. Perhaps find the last row based on column O, or column P?
- There's no need to use the `CONCATENATE` formula.

```
With WS
    ' find last row based on column O, or maybe P
    LastRow = .Range("O" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("C2:C" & LastRow).Formula = "=O2&""-""&P2"
End With
```

If you actually want hard-coded strings instead of cell references in your formula, then:

```
With WS
    ' find last row based on column O, or maybe P
    LastRow = .Range("O" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 to LastRow
       Range("C" & i).Formula = "=""" & Range("O" & i).Value & "-" & Range("P" & i).Value & """"
    Next 
End With
```

Comment: so I don't need to active a worksheet before doing anything in it? I don't quite understand what the difference is between activating a sheet and referencing it in all of your cell calls. Onto your second bullet, I need to insert this formula into every field in this column, based on the corresponding fields in Column O & P, so how would I do this without looping? Lastly as to your question on my LastRow finding, Columns C, O, & P all are required fields in dataset this is exported from. I won't have to worry about not having values in O or P but some in C, so I just did the first one.

Comment: Correct, there is no need to activate a worksheet. There is no need to loop if you write a formula like `=O2&"-"&P2` to multi-cell range in column C. Excel will automatically update the references to `O3`, and `P3`, `O4` and `P4` as you go down column C.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am still in the stages where I forget things like Cells are only hardcoded when written like $A$1, so it didn't even occur to me I could do this without a loop. Also, your suggestion about not finding the last row based off of the column I am attempting to update was very good. The code was still not inputting anything, until I changed that to search Column O to find LastRow. Kinda makes sense as the macro running right before this deletes everything in column C (oops lol). 

I have gotten it to work thanks to your help, I appreciate it very much.